# Retrieve Defect Data per iteration

Tags: rally

I want to have a drop down menu that can let me choose a particular iteration from the list of all iterations and can display the defect data for that chosen iteration. I am very new to Rally API so might be a very simple question but your response would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Filterable Tree Grid](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-tree-grid) example that uses an iteration combobox to filter artifacts, including defects. See also a [Filterable Grid](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid) example that filters defects by State.

Here is an [app example](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/stories-by-iteration-grouped-initiative) that builds a grid of stories filtered by iteration combobox and grouped by "parent" initiatives. You may easily change it to build a grid of defects grouped by associated requirements.